# Google viewer mobile

Tags: mobile, google-docs

I'm using Google viewer to read PDF.

I do it in a mobile application and I can't scroll between pages, I have click on the button next or previous.

Is there a way to scroll to change page adding a get parm or something else

Answer (score 0):

if your project android then you can add webview settings javascript enabled like

```
WebView webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```